# iOS - Sharing with other apps from a custom UI

Tags: ios, iphone

How do applications, such as Spotify, implement custom UI for sharing with other installed apps?  It appears to be similar content to what's available in the native `UIActivityViewController`.

[image]

Comment: any update on this @RyanB

Comment: I ended up writing a React Native wrapper around this:  https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNExtensionExecutor